# How Slice<?> in JPA repository works?

Tags: spring-data-jpa

We need to send Pageable object that is fine.

We will use slice mainly if in UI you don't need to send no of pages, only prev & next.

But, how it internally works?

```
Page<Employee> findByFirstName(String firstName, Pageable pageable);

Slice<Employee> findByFirstName(String firstName, Pageable pageable);
```

Page will internally call query & again the same query with

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (last query) to find total elements.
```

Similarly, what Slice's queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the same as for `Page` except that it doesn't perform the `count`.

It might be of interest that the paging, i.e. the limiting to a certain batch of the result is done by calling `setFirstResult(int)` and `setMaxResult(int)`

Comment: can't you tell me that will be the 2nd query it will fire? Like for count pagination fire count(*), what slice fires?

Comment: There isn't a second statement to execute. It is just the base query augmented by calls to `setFirstResult` and `setMaxResult`.